# How to draw a leaf design of floatingactionbutton in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QqlV.png)

I used this code

```html
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(40.0), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0)),
```

but I am getting [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYLt6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just increase the radius of button

```
            Container(
              height: 250,
              width: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(400.0),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(400.0)),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just found the solution!!!
I was using the wrong shape. I was using **BeveledRectangleBorder** but now I am using **RoundedRectangleBorder** and it's working.

Comment: @MuhammadAsad please do accept the answer, if it helped you!